# XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '<' character in Silverlight xaml designer

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

since morning, i try to fix but no result yet. I dont make sense. It was working yesterday but today i got the error. Another interesting thing is that Line 7404, I do not have such a large line of code.

**`XmlException: Name cannot begin with the '<' character, hexadecimal value 0x3C. Line 7404, position 64.`**

StackTrace

```
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XContainer.ReadContentFrom(XmlReader r, LoadOptions o)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(XmlReader reader, LoadOptions options)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Parse(String text, LoadOptions options)
   at ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer.client_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.OnDownloadStringCompleted(DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
   at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadStringOperationCompleted(Object arg)
```

Answer (score 3):

The downloaded xml is not valid. 
The exception message refers to the returned xml, so you´ll have to go to Line 7404, position 64 of the returned xml and see how the error occured.

Comment: Thanks @Tomas Grosup, But it is not error at runtime, it is compile time. Please check screenshot, http://i.hizliresim.com/RydOnj.png

Comment: This is an runtime error, and the lines do refer to the xml.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your client_DownloadStringCompleted method and copy the xml string somewhere you can investigate it.

Comment: thrown the error is xaml designer. client_DownloadStringCompleted method was not written by me, i guess in component.

Comment: The component is downloading something from the internet, you may also to try to turn un http://www.telerik.com/fiddler and monitor you network activity. Then, you should see that request with the returned invalid xml.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this.

right click on the settings.settings file under the project and select Open With. select the automatic editor selector (xml) from the pop-up window. The settings.settings file will be opened in the xml editor